# Сканирование всех зависимостей по группе проектов

Tags: java, gradle, gitlab

Подскажите, есть ли какой то инструмент, позволяющий сканировать всё зависимости в группе проектов и выводит в каком то виде результат?
Например, есть проект A, B и C.
Проект A использует проект B и C, всё это лежит в одной группе в гитлаб, и в результате было что то типо A--->B, A--->C.

Comment: вероятно, тут требуется уточнение, какой именно смысл вы вкладываете в термин «сканирование». для этого нажмите [edit]